# Sequelize do not work when I use Op.and and Op.ne

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I use Sequelize to query my database.
I use Op.and and Op.ne in my query :

```
const Op = require('sequelize');
let subLevels = await SubAchievement.findAll({
    where: {
        [Op.and]: [
            { upLevel: level.id, },
            {
                level: {
                    [Op.ne]: 2
                }
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

when I run my program. i get this error:

```
(node:72806) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Invalid value { upLevel: 1 }
```

and I can not find `Op.ne` in `Op`, but `Op.and` can be found.

why?

Answer (score 0):

```
const Op = require('sequelize');
let subLevels = await SubAchievement.findAll({
    where: {
        [Op.and]: [
            { upLevel: { [Op.eq]: level.id, } }, // [Op.eq] is added
            { level: { [Op.ne]: 2 } }
        ]
    }
});
```

Comment: why?: i think, this is bug of the library